# Downloading builds from TeamCity

Tags: teamcity

Is there a way to download specific builds of a project in TeamCity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're actually looking to do is create artifacts in TeamCity. Artifacts are normally a build output which are then attached to the individual build runs so that you can download and review them at a later date. There's a walk through including the creation of build artifacts in [You're deploying it wrong! TeamCity, Subversion & Web Deploy part 5: Web Deploy with TeamCity](http://www.troyhunt.com/2010/11/you-deploying-it-wrong-teamcity_26.html).

Comment: I have now tried adding some artifact paths to put the content of \bin in a separate directory (although the path is rather obscure). How can I reference this artifact from the outside, so my users always can download the latest version by entering a url?

Comment: I'm not near a TeamCity server this week so I'll have to speculate, but I think you'll find the URL is predictable and will contain a variable for the build number. There's also a REST API available that can be used to pull back build info which you might find useful: http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TW/REST+API+Plugin

Answer (score 8):

You can use the build id, build number or one of the static build identifiers:

```
http://{TeamCity-Server}/repository/download/{BUILD_TYPE_ID}/{BUILD_NUMBER}/{ARTIFACT_PATH}
```

http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD65/Patterns+For+Accessing+Build+Artifacts

Comment: How do I set up TC to do this? Can it provide a listing of the different builds?

Comment: @lejon Can we confirm what it is you are trying to download. I got the impression that you are trying to download artifacts from a build, is this the case?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know what "artifacts" referes to.

Comment: @lejon What do you want to download, the output from a build or the source used for the build?

Comment: Both really. First the output though.

Comment: @lejon In order to get the output you need to store the output as artifacts. http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD65/Build+Artifact Once you have artifacts you can access them how I described above.

Answer (score 0):

we attach the .msi file generated from the build as an artifact containing the build number (you can use %env.BUILD_NUMBER% to find the artifact path).

Answer (score 0):

To get latest successful build artifacts from Team City you can use the following link templates:

- with guest authentication: `http://<buildServer>/guestAuth/downloadArtifacts.html?buildTypeId=<buildTypeId>&buildId=lastSuccessful`
- with your credentials: `http://<buildServer>/repository/downloadAll/<buildTypeId>/.lastSuccessful/artifacts.zip`
- with specific artifact: `http://<buildServer>/httpAuth/repository/download/<buildTypeId>/.lastSuccessful/<some file.ext>`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, one can download using REST API. It is also possible using [FluentTc](https://www.nuget.org/packages/fluenttc) library with fluent api:

Download artifacts of the latest successful build:

```
IConnectedTc connectedTc = new RemoteTc().Connect(a => a.ToHost("tc")
       .AsUser("MYUSERNAME", "MYPASSWORD"))

IBuild lastSuccessfulBuild = connectedTc.GetLastBuild(having => 
    having.BuildConfiguration(with => with.Id("FluentTc"))
    .Status(BuildStatus.Success));

IList<string> downloadedFiles = connectedTc.DownloadArtifacts(lastSuccessfulBuild.Id, 
            @"C:\DownloadedArtifacts");
```

Download specific file from artifacts of specific build by build Id:

```
string downloadedFile = connectedTc.DownloadArtifacts(
    buildId, 
    @"C:\DownloadedArtifacts", 
    "binaries.zip");
```